# Insert textbox values into database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

What is the easiest and most SQL-like way to insert textbox values into a SQL Server table? I found several ways, and all of them are too complicated for this simple thing I want to do.

Comment: can you give some examples of what you have found?

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2010/03/11/inserting-data-to-database-using-linq-to-sql.aspx

Comment: @elninho is that too complicated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If LINQ is too foreign for you, you can still do things the old-fashioned way:

```
string statement = "INSERT INTO mytable(mycolumn) VALUES (@text)";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(statement);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", myTextBox.Text);

try{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);
    connection.Open();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
} catch {
    //do exception handling stuff
}
```

**Edit:** Here's another version that uses `using` to ensure that messes are cleaned up:

```
string statement = "INSERT INTO mytable(mycolumn) VALUES (@text)";

using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(statement))
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString)) {
    try{
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", myTextBox.Text);
        connection.Open();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    } catch {
        //do exception handling stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 almost perfect - uses straight SQL, parametrized query - only gripe is: you should put `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` into `using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(...))` blocks to make sure they get properly disposed. ALso the `Parameters.AddWithValue` is OK but can be dangerous at times - I prefer to specifically define the `SqlDbType` to avoid any surprises.....

Comment: Agreed 100% on all suggestions. I just wanted to keep the example simple so that it didn't overwhelm the OP.

Comment: the using-thingy should not confuse, better to drop the try-catch in that case..? +1 if you put in the using statement.

Comment: @vidstige `try`/`catch` is a much more well-known concept than `using`. There is no equivalent to `using` in Java, for example. I put up an example with it anyway.

Comment: this has nothing to do with java, but alright. on a side note - avoid catching *all* exception like this `catch` since it might hide serious problems with your program and is therefore considered bad practice. Instead catch a more specific exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something quickly, use LINQ to SQL. It will take care of your Data Access Layer & Business objects.

Just go to LINQ to SQL Classes on Visual Studio & map your SQL server and add any tables you want to it.

Then you can use the objects it creates in your code behind to update values from textboxes.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
public string ConnectionString
{
    get
    {
        //Reading connection string from web.config
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionName"].ConnectionString;
    }
}

public bool InsertEmployee()
{
    bool isSaved = false;
    int numberOfRowsAffected = 0;
    string query = @"INSERT INTO Employee(EmployeeName, EmailAddress)
                        VALUES (@EmployeeName, @EmailAddress);
                        SELECT @@IDENTITY AS RowEffected";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmployeeName", txtEmployeeName.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmailAddress", txtEmailAddress.Text));
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cn.Open();
            object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            isSaved = Convert.ToInt32(result) > 0 ? true : false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        isSaved = false;
    }
    return isSaved;
}
```

But, in multiple layer or multi-tier application you do need to create DTO(Data Transfer Object) to pass the data from layer to layer(or tier to tier)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do it.  It looks complex because of the number of rows: [Inserting Data in SQL Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720188%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)